# HTML iframe cant show the site

Tags: html, css, iframe, instagram

I'm trying to put "subscribe" button from instagram via iframe. But it says that instagram site is blocking it.

How can I put instagram "subscribe" button on an empty site so that user could click it and be subscribed without reaching the actual instagram page?

I'm new at this so please be very precise in your response :)

Comment: You cant control external site with iframe. The called "secure browsers" block this resource. Unless you are trying to load Instagram page and frame only the unsubscribe button. Then the user click it...

Comment: I tested here.. Yeah it does not load. You would need to change the request header. But there are not how to discover the "pass" to the external site allow your request. When you access a website, it gets some secret information like where you're coming from, to then allow you to access some content, such as a video.. You can edit it with plugins like Mod Header or with xhttp request in javascript.. but as I said, there is no way to guess the attributes and values I think.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.